# Matter Modelers: Please support our community ads!

Tags: discussion, community-ads, sponsorship-and-advertising, site-promotion

### Existing Community Ads

**Needs more support:**

- [Mathematica Community Promotion Ads](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2617/4295) (updated to 2021 ad!)
- [Academia Community Promotion Ads](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4938/93303) (updated to 2021 ad!)
- [Ask Ubuntu Community Promotion Ads](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19618/676348) (updated to 2021 ad!)
- [Cryptography Community Promotion Ads](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1532/59140) (updated to 2021 ad!)
- [Software Engineering Community Promotion Ads](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9076/359157)
- [Electrical Engineering Community Promotion Ads](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7141/192433)
- [Theoretical Computer Science Community Promotion Ads](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3050/35155)
- [Mechanics Community Promotion Ads](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2083/44515)
- [Signal Processing Community Promotion Ads](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1676/38860)
- [Computer Science Community Promotion Ads](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1695/61663)
- [Software Recommendations Community Promotion Ads](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2897/40237)
- [Cross Validated Community Promotion Ads](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6161/211119) (updated to 2021 ad!)

**Needs to be added:**

- [TeX Community Promotion Ads](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8792/14527) (updated to 2021 ad!)
- [Android Community Promotion Ads](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2655/110778) (updated to 2021 ad!)
- [AskDifferent Community Promotion Ads](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4006/365497) (updated to 2021 ad!)
- We can add ads to any other sites you think may be appropriate (CodeGolf and other sites)

**Thanks for the support! More help wouldn't harm though:**

- [Unix/Linux Community Promotion Ads](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5796/78288) (updated to 2021 ad!)
- [Graphics Design Community Promotion Ads](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3700/131244)
- [Data Science Community Promotion Ads](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2577/91311) (updated to 2021 ad!)
- [Biology Community Promotion Ads](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4213/719) (updated to 2021 ad!)
- [Chemistry Community Promotion Ads](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5032/27342) (updated to 2021 ad!)
- [Physics Community Promotion Ads](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13631/134583) (updated to 2021 ad!)
- [Computational Science Community Promotion Ads](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/560/27325)
- [Mathematics Community Promotion Ads](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33728/202425) (updated to 2021 ad!)

### Science Helping Science Ads

**Unfortunately these also need support (2 were deleted because of lack of enough upvotes):**

- [Physics Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/consider-supporting-proposals-of-other-se-science-sites)
- [Chemistry Meta](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4675/27342)
- [Astronomy Meta](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/588/33303)
- [Earth Science Meta](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1856/18946)
- [History of Science and Mathematics Meta](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/325/8052)
- [Engineering Meta](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/616/18132)
- [Mathematics Educators Meta](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/668/13687)
- [Open Data Meta](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/448/24779)

### More places to add the "science helping science" ads:

- [Space Meta](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/) (they are advertised on all of the above already, they might be welcoming).
- [Operations Research Meta](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/) (they are advertised in some of the above already).
- [Robotics Meta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/) (they are advertised in all of the above already).
- [Artificial Intelligence Meta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence) (edit 60 of the Physics ad shows they were advertised there).
- [CompSci Meta](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/)  (edit 49 of the Physics ad shows they were advertised there).
- [Data Science Meta](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/) (edit 40 of the Physics ad shows they were advertised there).
- [Sustainable Living Meta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33364/sustainable-living)  (edit 17 of the Physics ad shows they were advertised there).
- [Cognitive Science Meta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2149/cognitive-science) (edit 2 of the Physics ad shows they were advertised there).
- [Biology Meta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12502/biology) (edit 1 of the Physics ad shows they were advertised there).
- [Psychology Meta](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/) (edit 1 of the Physics ad shows that an earlier Psychology site was advertised there).
- [Bioinformatics Meta](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/) (they don't yet have the generic ad that the above sites have, but they are still in Beta so they would benefit from the help).
- [Economics Meta](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/) (they don't yet have the generic ad that the above sites have, but they are still in Beta so they would benefit from the help).
- [Computer Science Meta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science) (they graduated before the original Physics ad was made).
- [Cross Validated Meta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33/statistical-analysis) (they graduated before the original Physics ad was made).
- [Theoretical Computer Science](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8766/theoretical-computer-science) (they graduated before the original Physics ad was made).
- Any other sites you think may be appropriate
- We can also put a free Community Promotion Ad on [PhysicsOverflow](https://www.physicsoverflow.org/19675).

Comment: We are just one upvote away from having the Computational Science ad displayed.

Comment: New 2021 community post pages have been posted on the all non-Beta sites.

Comment: @Tyberius let's be the first to go up on each site!

Comment: @Tyberius The 2021 ads appear only to be available on CrossValidated, DataScience, Biology, Chemistry, Physics, and Mathematics. I've added the ads (all as Community Wiki this time) to all of those sites though if you're able to take a look!

Comment: Interestingly, right now the CS add was at -1. For the life of me I cannot imagine why someone would have an issue with the ad, but nobody bothered to add a comment either. Oh my.

Comment: @AnoE Some users want to keep the ads on their sites very narrowly focused. Some don't want to see any ads at all, so they just downvote all of them.

Comment: @Tyberius the CS ad is now at 0 (so thanks AnoE if you're the one that corrected the -1 !!). The CS ad was from 2020 though, when it looked like this: https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/1695/1. In other words, MMSE did not even exist yet !!! Our new ad with the new design, has been more well received across the board. AnoE, I'd recommend looking at the ads listed in this post, which have "updated to 2021" next to them, and supporting them if you'd like to! Unfortunately many sites like CS don't have voting open yet for 2021 ads.